# Upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10 broke login

Tags: gdm

I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 but login is all messed up.  Login is "command prompt", or whatever it's called.  I have to type in my login credentials then startx to load desktop session.

I need a login manager to I can choose fallback environment.  Whatever is default doesn't work right. Not full screen.

Comment: have you tried fixing broken packages like xorg using `dpkg --reconfigure -a` ? and doing an autoremove?

Comment: Have you tried using Xorg instead of Wayland?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --remove /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to finish upgrade without systemd-shim error.  And restored gdm3

```
sudo service gdm3 restart
```

Then installing drivers worked so was able to get my full screen resolution.

Note: using lightdm doesn't work.  Couldn't login.  There was login loop.

Comment: JoeSteiger, if this solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as SOLVED by clicking on the checkmark at left.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if a package may have been corrupted during the install.

### Try manually running gdm

First thing to try is to manually invoke `gdm`:

```
sudo service gdm restart
```

if this fails, look at the errors with:

```
sudo service gdm status
```

and post them, or continue with the other steps.

### Fixing most broken packages

Most broken packages can be fixed with a simple:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

### Reinstalling

If `apt install -f` doesn't help, then try reinstalling `gdm`, the display manager:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gdm
```

### Try lightdm

As I've personally haven't had much experience with Ubuntu 17.10, I'm not sure if this would work, but it's worth a shot:

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

This will install `lightdm`, the display manager used before ubuntu switched to `gdm`.

Answer (score 0):

There was a failure in gnome-packages of version 3.28.0 (3.28.1) which concerned gdm. Then gdm had cipher-salad. Apparently this looked like an attempt of attack where somebody tried to install ransomware.

In gnome-packages of version 3.28.2 this bug (ransomware?) is fixed.

You for Ubuntu would have to wait until next update of gnome-packages.